# Alternatives to pandas.merge because of "array is too big" value error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm creating a function that inputs a dataframe (pulled from a csv file) with the format:

| Date | Stock1 | Date | Stock2 | Date | Stock3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | 100 | 01/01/2000 | 12.1 | 01/01/2000 | 54 |
| 03/01/2000 | 101 | 02/01/2000 | 12.5 | 03/01/2000 | 50 |
| 04/01/2000 | 104 | 03/01/2000 | 12.2 | 05/01/2000 | 49 |

for any number of stocks and any number of dates, and outputs a dataframe as follows:

| Date | Stock1 | Stock2 | Stock3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | 100 | 12.1 | 54 |
| 03/01/2000 | 101 | 12.2 | 50 |

i.e. all the dates that do not exist in all the stock price time series are discarded.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
def collectdata(df):
    n = (len(df.columns))
    data = df.iloc[:,0:2].copy()
    data.columns = ['Date', data.columns[1]]
    for i in range(2,n,2):
        x = df.iloc[:,i:i+2].copy()
        x.columns=['Date', x.columns[1]]
        data = pd.merge(data, x)
    return data
 
# example: we have a file called test.csv:

dataset = collectdata(pd.read_csv('test.csv'))
print(dataset.head())
```

The code works fine for smaller data sets, but when I attempted with a data set of 15 stocks with and 5000 rows I got:
*ValueError: array is too big*

I believe this problem is arising because I am using pd.merge (as I can pull the dataset with no problem). Is there an alternative to this that I can use that will eliminate this error? (Or equally a more efficient way around this problem?)

Comment: How big are effectively `data` and `x` just before the error? (see `data.shape` and `x.shape`)

Comment: What is the goal for the output? Only return results where 1st Date column = 3rd Date column and consolidate to one Date column?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Hi, in the first iteration of the loop data.shape is (7390,2) and in the second it jumps to (20487965,3) and then the error hits. x.shape stays at (7390,2).

Comment: @Gage Hi, the goal is to get the dates into the first column, but only the dates that appear in all of the timeseries. So in the example in the question, only 01/01/2000 and 03/01/2000 appear in all three of the stocks' timeseries, so they are the only dates to be collected.